# Inserting an ISO8601 DATETIME throws errors

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, mariadb

So I've been trying this for a whole day now and I feel like there's a super simple solution and i'm just missing it. Attempting to use this query:

```
INSERT INTO codes (`user_id`, `type`, `code`, `expires`) VALUES ($id, $type, $code, $expires);
```

Here is the "expires" value:

`2016-11-13T00:14:43.000Z`

The error that comes out of querying:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':14:43.000Z)' at line 1
```

Here's the database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS codes (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`expires` DATETIME
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I do use a real_escape_string on the $expires variable if that matters.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datetime values like `2016-11-13T00:14:43.000Z` are text strings. You need to enclose them in single quotes in the VALUES clauses of your insert statements.

In fact, you need single quotes around all your values, because they are all text strings.

```
 INSERT INTO codes (user_id, type, code, expires) VALUES ('$id', '$type', '$code', '$expires');
```

To understand this, let's say you have a `$code` value of `143-101`. If you do

```
 INSERT INTO junk (code) VALUES ($code)
```

from your php program, the MySQL server will see

```
 INSERT INTO junk (code) VALUES (143-101)
```

which will yield the column value `42`.  That will make Douglas Adams happy, but nobody else.

You want your MySQL server to see

```
 INSERT INTO junk (code) VALUES ('143-101')
```

which you can do with

```
 INSERT INTO junk (code) VALUES ('$code')
```

And, if this application is accessible to the global internet, you **must** study up on SQL injection and make your SQL injection-proof, or some cybercriminal **will** pwn you and steal your assets.

Comment: Unknown column 'Subscriber' in 'field list'.

The $type variable is "Subscriber".

I was getting this error when trying that previously. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nick, same issue. That is a string, it needs quotes around the `$type` variable or else the database thinks you are trying to reference a database object.

Comment: I feel so stupid. Thank you so much for the explanation <3

Comment: There's only one stupid question: the one you don't ask. There *is* stupid code on the internet though. So be careful.